# HTMLDOC does not execute from PHP

Tags: php, htmldoc

I am trying to create a PDF from an HTML file from a PHP page (Apache, LAMP)  Wierd thing is, when I execute the script from the command line, it works and creates the PDF as expected.  However when I browse to the page in my browser, it does nothing.  I'm thinking it's a permissions issue somewhere, but I'm stumped!  Here's the code.   (NOTE the ls command DOES produce output in the browser so it's not just an issue of PHP not being allowed to execute shell commands)

```
    <?php 
    $htmlName = ("output2/alex" . time() . ".html");
    $pdfName = ("output2/alex" . time() . ".pdf");
    $html = "<html><body><h1>Hello, World!</h1></body></html>";

    $fileHandle = fopen($htmlName, "w+");

    fwrite($fileHandle, $html);
    fclose($fileHandle);

    $command= "htmldoc -t pdf --browserwidth 1000 --embedfonts --header ... --footer t./ --headfootsize 5.0 --fontsize 9 --bodyfont Arial --size letter --top 4 --bottom 25 --left 28 --right 30 --jpeg --webpage $options '$htmlName' -f '$pdfName'";

    echo "OUTPUT: \r\n";
    $X=passthru($command);

    echo "TESTING LS:";
    $y=passthru("ls -al");

    if(file_exists($htmlName) && file_exists($pdfName)) {
        echo "Success.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, it did not create a PDF";
    }
?>
```

When I execute the script from the command line it produces the expected output, and creates a PDF file like it's supposed to:

```
> php alextest.php
Zend OPcache requires Zend Engine API version 220131226.
The Zend Engine API version 220100525 which is installed, is outdated.

OUTPUT:
PAGES: 1
BYTES: 75403
TESTING LS:total 2036
drwxr-xr-x  9  ----- and so on...
```

When I browse the page in Chrome, it outputs only the LS command.

help!?

Comment: Also, I chowned the output2 directory to apache:apache and chmod'ed it to 777, thinking that maybe that was the issue.  Still no workie.  It does write the html file just fine, but not the PDF.

Comment: What does the php-error-log say, if anything? Or the Apache one?

Comment: @AlexRussell: Not exactly a solution for your problem, but if you’re trying to convert HTML to PDF in PHP, have a look at DOMPDF or (though rather limited in this regard) TCPDF. Excecuting shell commands is dirty and not exactly portable.

Comment: lxg, great minds think alike! I was just thinking switching it over to domPDF may be the best route.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using a full path as your php file my be executing in a different directory than it is saved in depending on how it is loaded.  (IE via `include`, `require`, or `.htaccess` or directly by apache.)

IE

```
$htmlName = ("/home/alex/html/output2/alex" . time() . ".html");
$pdfName = ("/home/alex/html/output2/output2/alex" . time() . ".pdf");
```

I agree with the comments that using a package like http://dompdf.github.io/ or https://tcpdf.org/ would be best though.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same issue, and for the life of me I simply couldn't find the answer to why it wouldn't do it from a web based call, but never a problem from the command line. So, instead of fighting my way to a solution on that front, I created a Perl proxy to allow me to parse PDFs from the command line making it useful for virtually any given purpose. For, with Perl, I've never had a problem parsing PDFs, and I've been doing it for decades now.

So, here's what you do. PHP Code:

```
exec("/usr/local/bin/perl5 -s /path/to/perl/executable/parse-pdf-from-html-document.pl -source=markup-file.html",$output);

foreach ($output as $aline) {
    #- WAS SUCCESSFUL
    if (strstr($aline,'Successful!') == TRUE) {
        #- no feedback, win silently
    }
    #- NOT SUCCESSFUL
    else {
        echo $aline . "\n";
    }
}
```

With `$output` holding the results of running exec.

Now let's look at the Perl code for parse-pdf-from-html-document.pl:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl5 -s

#- $document coming from commandline variable, via caller: PHP script
$myDocumentLocale = "/path/to/markup/document/".$document;
if (-e $myDocumentLocale) {
    $documentHTML = $myDocumentLocale;
    $documentPDF = $documentHTML;
    $documentPDF =~ s/\.html/\.pdf/gi;

    $myDocumentHTML = `cat $myDocumentLocale`;

    $badPDF = 0;
    $myPDFDocumentLocale = $myDocumentLocale;
    $myPDFDocumentLocale =~ s/\.html/\.pdf/gi;
    $badPDF = &parsePDF($myDocumentLocale, $myPDFDocumentLocale);

    if ($badPDF == 0) {
        print "Successful!";
    }
    else {
        print "Error: No PDF Created.";
    }
    exit;

    }
else {
    print "Error: No document found.";
    exit;
}

sub parsePDF {
    my ($Ihtml, $Ipdf) = @_;
    $wasBad = 0;

    #- create PDF
    $ENV{HTMLDOC_NOCGI} = 1;
    $commandline="/usr/local/bin/htmldoc -t pdf13 --pagemode document --header ... --footer ... --left 1cm --size Letter --webpage -f $Ipdf $Ihtml";
    select(STDOUT); 
    $| = 1;
    #print "Content-Type: application/pdf\n\n";
    system($commandline);
    if (-e $Ipdf) {
        $wasBad = 0;
    }
    else {
        $wasBad = 1;
    }
    return $wasBad;
}

exit;
```

Comment: My apologies for it taking so long for me to post this answer, I just haven't been around for a while. However, I am always interested in helping people better understand technology, so with that being said, I do love HTMLDOC and always will, time to help others do the same.